# Monstera adansonii dying

Tags: monstera

[image]

I just repot them and its been 2 days. I think it was a bit like this when I got it. I have water but not wet. I put in indirect sunlight.

Comment: That looks to me that it is very, very dehydrated.   First thing I would do is absolutely soak it in water (if possible, immerse the whole pot in water for a few minutes  until the bubbles are gone).   As an aside, I've seen plants which I've watered every day be very dehydrated until I immersed them in water - and then they came back within hours.  You can often tell if this is the problem because the plant/bucket feels light for the amount of soil you see)